# Extended stored procedure xp_create_subdir returns "Invalid Parameter" message

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, subdirectory

Since version 2005 Microsoft SQL Server allows creating path if it's not exist. Simply call stored procedure with parameter leading to desired path on disk.

```
DECLARE @targetDirectory nvarchar(max) = N'E:\backup' 
exec xp_create_subdir @targetDirectory
```

So, if you write code above into query pane in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, you receive following error message:

> Msg 22048, Level 15, State 0, Line 0
>   Error executing extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter

It's strange that if you change code to

```
exec xp_create_subdir N'E:\backup'
```

and execute it, directory is created at desired path, assuming that sql service account has rights to write.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although nvarchar(max) has maximum length of 2GB characters, if you change @targetDirectory variable declaration to

```
DECLARE @targetDirectory nvarchar(4000) = N'E:\backup'
```

and execute following statement

```
exec xp_create_subdir @targetDirectory
```

you successfully create subdirectory backup on disk E: if it not exists and return message

> Command(s) completed successfully.
>   in the message window.

The reason is that stored procedure **xp_create_subdir doesn't accept nvarchar(max) data type**.

**EDIT:**According to [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) comment, the reason was that variable length was different in statements above.

Comment: nvarchar(max) does NOT have a length of 4000. It will consume as much storage as the data requires up to a maximum of 2^31-1 bytes or 2GB. Glad figured out the solution to your problem. :)

Comment: Don't forget about the Windows 260 character limitation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) on filepaths as well.  Even though it doesn't directly relate to your issue, you may want to strongly type the input parameter to 260 characters instead of the 4000 you have defined.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I hope that SQL Server for Linux will not suffer with the same issue.

Comment: Likely not as it's an OS limitation and not something tied to the database engine.  Linux generally looks to have a 4096 character filepath limit and a 255 character limit on the filename (http://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux).